# Call Microsoft Graph API without refreshing authorization to API every time

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am want to use the `Microsoft Graph API` to get data from my outlook mailbox.

Using **https://github.com/O365/python-o365#authentication** and help from SO I have managed to connect to the `Microsoft Graph API` using the `On behalf of a user (public)` auth method.

This method returns a URL into the console which then needs to be copied into a browser to Authorize.

Surely I don't have to do this every time I call the `Graph API`??, and if im  reading the above DOC correctly, I don't.

I believe I need to store the `AUTH` token given back from the `URL` and then use that when calling the `Graph API`? But I am having trouble implementing this into my code. Possibly using `connection.request_token` to store the token and then `account.is_authenticated`?

This is my first go at working with an API with this type of `Auth` method

Here is what I have so far.. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction

```
from O365 import Account, FileSystemTokenBackend

credentials = ('my_client_ID',)
token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path=(r'C:\Users\Desktop', token_filename = 'my_token.txt')
account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type = 'public', token_backend = token_backend)
account.authenticate(scopes = ['Mail.Read', 'offline_access'])
```

Comment: In case you're not aware, Microsoft maintain their own PyPI package [msal](https://pypi.org/project/msal/).  [How to guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-python-token-cache-serialization).

Comment: How can we do this in Java? I have written code but it requires sign in. I want to read my emails without sign in

Comment: microsofts own guides suck and leave me more confused than before I started